# fping – How to make fping result always sequential in order of command line

Tags: linux, shell, ping

I want to get the result of `fping` always sequential
in the order of the command line arguments.

For example, the command:

```
fping -e 151.101.129.164 8.8.8.8
```

might give the output:

```
8.8.8.8 is alive (5.43 ms)
151.101.129.164 is alive (63.2 ms)
```

The result above is in a different order than the arguments to the `fping` command, where `151.101.129.164` is put first in the `fping` command but the result shows second.

How can the `151.101.129.164` display first in result without change the order of the first fping command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to write a wrapper script:

```
#!/bin/sh
myfile=$(mktemp)
fping "$@" > "$myfile"
for arg
do
        case "$arg" in
          (-*)  # Ignore options
                ;;
          (*)   grep "^$arg " "$myfile"
        esac
done
rm "$myfile"
```

So, if you call this `myfping`,
and you run `myfping -e 151.101.129.164 8.8.8.8`
(where you either need to prepend `./`
or put the script in a directory that’s in your PATH),
it will run

  ```
  fping -e 151.101.129.164 8.8.8.8
  ```

with output to a temporary file,
and then go through the arguments in command-line (left-to-right) order
and pull out the results in order.

Notes:

- The IPv4 address parser is very flexible;
  on most (if not all) systems,
  it will interpret `127.0.1` as equivalent to `127.0.0.1`. 
  So, if you `fping 127.0.1`,
  and `fping` produces a line of output that begins `127.0.1`,
  and you also have an argument like `1.7.0.1`,
  that will be treated as a regular expression that matches `127.0.1`. 
  You can overcome this as follows:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  myfile=$(mktemp)
  ./fping "$@" > "$myfile"
  for arg
  do
          case "$arg" in
            (-*)  # Ignore options
                  ;;
            (*)   darg=$(sed 's/\./\\./g' <<< "$arg")
                  grep "^$darg " "$myfile"
          esac
  done
  rm "$myfile"
  ```

  where an `arg` of `1.7.0.1` will be converted to a `darg` of `1\.7\.0\.1`,
  which will not match `127.0.1`.

  The above script is bash-specific
  because of the “here string” (`<<< "$arg"`). 
  You can make this POSIX-compliant by changing the `darg=` line to

  ```
  darg=$(printf "%s" "$arg" | sed 's/\./\\./g')
  ```
- The above might be a red herring. 
  If you `fping 127.0.1`,
  then `fping` *might* normalize the address
  and report the result for `127.0.0.1`;
  then the `grep` wouldn’t find that. 
  Or maybe not; check your version of `fping`.
- If you use any options that have arguments,
  like `-c count` or `-I interface`,
  the `case` logic in my script will treat the option arguments
  as if they were ordinary arguments; i.e., target host names / addresses. 
  This probably won’t matter.
- If you have an argument that contains `*`, `[`…`]`,
  or some other special characters, `grep` may produce unexpected results. 
  This doesn’t seem to be likely to be a problem in real life.
- If `fping` outputs any information
  that doesn’t correspond to a target host name / address argument,
  you won’t see it.
- This script does not exit with the exit status from `fping`. 
  Fixing that is left as an exercise.